# Clone the first two text box values of a current row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, clone

I have a requirement that for a table has the add row button and delete row button which I show in the following code.

For adding a row I want to clone the first two values "who" and "Location" of the current row  to get the next row when I click on add row. In case I have different details on "who" and "Location" on third row when I click on "Add row" it has to take the same details of the third row and add the fourth row with the details of "who" and "location" in third row.

Hope you understand this scenario.

Html Table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="who" name="who" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="location" name="location" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /table#table-data -->
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
        var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);
    });
    </script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function deleteRow(r)
{
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("table-data").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep/b6A9R/ click on add row that create new row along first two value of the current row "WHO" and "Location"

Comment: you want to copy the first and second column data of the current row to the newly added row? So If you write test in both name and location then it should be added in the second row as well right?

Comment: I am Placing this concept to existing table .when i did the add row it has to take the existing current row value to next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I had miss understood the question, since you need not require the dates, here is your answer and an update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6A9R/3/)

Code Snippet:

```
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find('.datepicker').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: Won't do because he wants start date and end date to be empty for next row. So he has added that line.

Answer (score 2):

**Your problem**: Trying to change `input` value before adding it in HTML markup.

**Solution**: Change value after adding element to HTML.

Also, using class selector `.datepicker` would be better in this case.

This will work,

```
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    console.log($tr);
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $tr.after($clone);
    $($clone).find(".datepicker").val('');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6A9R/4/)**

Comment: No need to loop on the datepicker class

Answer (score 1):

**Working JS Fiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/D36ZL/1/**

**Your HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="who" name="who" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="location" name="location" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /table#table-data -->
```

**Some jQuery:**

```
$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $tr.after($clone);
    $clone.find('.datepicker').val('');
});
```

Using `$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {` is a better way, since you are generating the HTML dynamically.

Cheers!

## Update:

As mentioned, there is no need to put class datepicker in loop, hence altered the solution.

Comment: No need to loop on the datepicker class